# Rails 4 REST handle multiple JSON hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

So far we have an REST API that accepts a simple hash for a user like this like this one :

```
{
  name : "name",
  address : "address"
  password . "testtest"
}
```

This works so far. Now we would like to put multiple json records into one POST request and let the controller store each record in the database.

```
{   
"user":[
    {
     "name ": "name1",
     "address" : "addr2"
    },
    {
     "name ": "name1",
     "address" : "addr2"
    }
   ]
 }
```

Webrick log:

```
 Started POST "/api/user" for ::1 at 2015-10-29 17:41:49 +0100
 Processing by Api::UserController#create as JSON
 Parameters: {"{\"user\":"=>{"{\"name\": \"name1\",\"address\": \"addr1\"},{\"name\": \"name2\",\"address\": \"addr2\"}"=>{"}"=>nil}}}
Unpermitted parameters: {"user":, format
 (0.3ms)  BEGIN
 (2.5ms)  ROLLBACK
 Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 13ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

The parameter list for WEbrick looks a bit shaky. Also that the top level item  `user` shows up in the  unpermitted parameter set makes sense since i dont want a user as a user object itself, but more an array of user hashes, or do i?
I use this curl to create the request

```
curl -u test:test -v -X  POST -d '{"user":["name": "name1","address": "addr1"},{"name": "name2","address": "addr2"]}' http://localhost:3000/api/user
```

which gives me

```
{"name":["can't be blank"],"address":["can't be blank"]}%
```

On the model i have presence constraints on the name and address field.
I tried to enclose the permit.params with rectanguar brankets to accept an array which is not really working. I also  added an attribute_accessor `:user` to my user model.

```
  private
    def user_params
      params.permit(user: [:name,:address])
    end
```

I think i somehow change my create methods that is accepts something like 
    user[0]
    user[1] 
But i am not sure if this is the way to go? 
Thanks anyone for reading & helping!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an error in the json you're posting, it should read

```
curl -u test:test -v -X  POST -d '{"user":[{"name": "name1","address": "addr1"},{"name": "name2","address": "addr2"}]}' http://localhost:3000/api/user
```

Comment: Oh yeah,  but i stll get the 422 unprocessable entry error, but the log looks a bit cleaner now.